# How to orderBy unique name in column in Java Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

This will probably better explain the title.

Basically the user who has given the most ratings on each genre. One user can vote for multiple genres so hence why top 9 is the same user. The table "exploded" contains two rows. One has userId and the other has the genres he's voted on. One user can vote for multiple genres.

The code I am using is:

```
Dataset<Row> group = exploded.groupBy("userId", "genres").count().orderBy(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("count").desc());
```

And the result from it is the following:

```
+------+--------+-----+
|userId|genres  |count|
+------+--------+-----+
|45811 |Drama   |10296|
|8659  |Drama   |4879 |
|270123|Drama   |4372 |
|45811 |Comedy  |4239 |
|228291|Drama   |3932 |
|179792|Drama   |3690 |
|98415 |Drama   |3586 |
|243331|Drama   |3466 |
|8659  |Comedy  |3294 |
|229879|Drama   |3234 |
|172224|Drama   |3041 |
|41190 |Drama   |3009 |
|24025 |Drama   |2846 |
|166928|Drama   |2696 |
|243443|Comedy  |2668 |
|32984 |Drama   |2662 |
|45811 |Thriller|2578 |
|45811 |Romance |2533 |
|101276|Comedy  |2516 |
|179792|Comedy  |2511 |
+------+--------+-----+
```

There is a big chance I'm using the wrong methods.

Here is the result I'm looking for:

```
+------+--------+-----+
|userId|genres  |count|
+------+--------+-----+
|45811 |Drama   |10296|
|45811 |Comedy  |4879 |
|45811 |Thriller|4372 |
|45811 |Romance |4239 |
|45811 |Crime   |3932 |
|45811 |Documentary|3690 |
|45811 |Action  |3586 |
|243331|Horror  |3466 |
|45811 |Adventure|3294 |
|45811 |Sci-Fi   |3234 |
+------+--------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

try group by only "genres"

```
Dataset<Row> group = exploded.groupBy("userId", "genres").count().orderBy(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("count").desc());
```

Comment: That's not what I want because I need the userId as well. Basically the user who has given the most ratings on each genre. Not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: then you should use .max() instead of .count() 
exploded.groupBy("genres").agg(max(count)).orderBy(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("count").desc());

Comment: i made a query for your problem and it worked fine as you asked
select userid,genres,max(count) from table GROUP by genres order by count desc
use this query in javaspark it will work i hopeso :)

Comment: exploded.groupBy("genres").agg(max(count)).orderBy(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("count").desc()); gives an error at count though ?

Comment: yes i forgot to add "" to count try this now and tell
exploded.groupBy("genres").agg(max("count")).orderBy(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("count").desc());

Comment: Getting max underlined as error now, when I do org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max I can run it but I get an exception :  cannot resolve '`count`' given input columns.

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("count") use this within max()

Comment: Same problem: cannot resolve '`count`' given input columns: [userId, genres];; when I write in: Dataset<Row> group = exploded.groupBy("genres").agg(max(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("count"))).orderBy(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("count").desc());

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dataset<Row> group = exploded.groupBy("userId", "genres")
.count()
.orderBy(col("count").desc())
.groupBy("genres")
.agg(
    first(col(count)).as("count")
    first(col(genres)).as("genres")
    first(col(userId)).as("userId")
);
```

You shouldn't have to use agg max as you've already ordered the count descending. Just building on the results you already had I've grouped by the genre again and selected the first row (which will be the highest because of the previous order)

Alternatively, you could try a Window function and perform a count().over(windowSpec) where window spec partitions by genre and user id and orders by count. You then do another group by genre and select the first rows like above.